# Azure Get-AzureRmMlService not found Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, machine-learning

How do I get the azure web service from powershell? I am following [the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-retrain-new-web-service-using-powershell), which says I need to *call the Get-AzureRmMlWebService cmdlet*. But when I follow the command line in the doc and run `Get-AzureRmMlWebService`, it says the term is not recognized. Any body knows how to solve the issue? I also tried `npm install azure-cli --global` and `Add-AzureRmAccount`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the Azure modules. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/powershell-install-configure

```
Install-Module AzureRM
```

This will get it from *powershellgallery.com*.

Comment: The link directs me to the right direction. It worked after installing the azure power shell. Thanks!